# How to define and test Trigger in Azure Cosmos DB (Graph DB with Gemline API)?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

How to define and test Trigger in Azure Cosmos DB (Graph DB with Gemline API) ?